# How to get generic factory to typecheck constructor of different classes?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given this example:

```
    class OneArgConstructorClass {
        constructor(name: string) {}
    }
    class TwoArgConstructorClass {
        constructor(name: string, age: number) {}
    }
    class Creator<T>
    {
        constructor(tConstructor: new(...args: any[])=> T) {
            const it: T = new tConstructor();
        }
    }

    const e1 = new Creator<OneArgConstructorClass>(OneArgConstructorClass); 
    const e2 = new Creator<OneArgConstructorClass>(TwoArgConstructorClass);
```

Why are e1 and e2 valid statements? Shouldn't typescript complain that it can't correctly construct e1/e2 without the proper number and type of arguments? Is it possible to make this sample properly typechecked against the passed in class constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason there is no error is because your `tConstructor` parameter takes any number of parameters of any type.

If you want to be more restrictive about which parameters are allowed you could use tuple types to specify exactly which parameters `tConstructor` takes, e.g.:

```
class Creator<T>
{
    constructor(tConstructor: new (...args: [string]) => T) {
    //                                      ^^^^^^^^
    // note that args is a tuple containing exactly one item, namely a string
        const it: T = new tConstructor();
        //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // This is now wrong because the constructor takes a string as parameter
    }
}

const e1 = new Creator<OneArgConstructorClass>(OneArgConstructorClass);
const e2 = new Creator<OneArgConstructorClass>(TwoArgConstructorClass);
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// This is now also wrong because the constructor signatures are not compatible
```

If you made `...args`'s signature `[string, number]` then your call of `new tConstructor()` would still be wrong because you haven't given it its 2 required parameters, but `new Creator<OneArgConstructorClass>(TwoArgConstructorClass)` would be fine as it now receives its correct 2 parameters.

Unlike what you may expect though, `new Creator<OneArgConstructorClass>(OneArgConstructorClass)` also doesn't throw an error anymore because the constructor that accepts 1 parameter will safely ignore whatever additional parameters it receives.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you want a typesafe way of calling the class constructors you need to do something like this:

```
// Note the constraint that T must be "new"able
class Creator<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>
{
    // ConstructorParameters is a builtin TS utility that when given a class returns the type of its parameters in a tuple
    // Note that we need to pass the actual parameters in somehow; in this example I've made Creator#constructor take 2 parameters:
    // 1) the class
    // 2) its constructor parameters in a tuple
    constructor(tConstructor: new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => any,
        argsArray: ConstructorParameters<T>) {

        // Construct the class with the arguments array!
        const it: T = new tConstructor(...argsArray);
    }
}

// This will now work
const e1 = new Creator<typeof OneArgConstructorClass>(OneArgConstructorClass, ['hello']);

// This will now *not* work, which is correct, as the constructor signatures don't match
const e2 = new Creator<typeof OneArgConstructorClass>(TwoArgConstructorClass, ['hello', 14]);
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Argument of type 'typeof TwoArgConstructorClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (name: string) => any'.

// This *will* work because the signatures match
const e3 = new Creator<typeof TwoArgConstructorClass>(TwoArgConstructorClass, ['hello', 14]);
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I do change tConstructor to take a tuple type to specify exactly which parameters it takes, it sounds like that signature is now directly coupled to the specific type being passed in and can't really be used generically for different types with different constructors? Unless they have overlapping constructor parameters and one throws away any unnecessary ones. Is there a way to I guess generically take parameters and then at the point of construction validate that it is being constructed correctly?

Comment: Wow, yes it does, thank you so much! I just played around with it, and that is exactly what I have been trying to achieve. Really appreciate your help! So I have 1 final follow up question/possible wrench(which I can possibly live without). Is it possible to specify a partial number of arguments via ConstructorParameters and still typecheck? e.g. I would like Creator to specify the 1st name parameter when constructing all types, and then the callers of it would pass in the remaining arguments. So all but their 1st arg, and Creator would combine all args at the point of construction.

Comment: To give more context on what I am ultimately trying to achieve, I would like to create the same class N times with all the same arguments except the name.  

    const c = Creator<typeof TwoArgConstructorClass>(["red", "blue"], 
    TwoArgConstructorClass, [35]). 
  
    // so c creates 2 instances of TwoArgConstructorClass. 
    // 1st: TwoArgContructorClass("red", 35);  
    // 2nd: TwoArgConstructorClass("blue", 35);

Comment: I've tried a few things but can't come up with a way to do it - and certainly not without heavily abusing the type system. I'll make another edit if I do come up with a way to do it. Glad I could help so far though!